# Multiple Select List and KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a multi-select list that I've implemented [following the instructions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) on the KO site. The important portions of my code currently look like this (removed unnecessary code):

```
function Attribute(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = data.Id;
    self.Name = data.Name;
}

// Individual Row in Table
function Criteria(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Attributes = data.Attributes;
}

// Represent the ViewModel for attributes.
function CriteriaViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Catalog Data
    self.availableAttributes = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON(window.attributeListUrl, function(availableData) {
        self.availableAttributes($.map(availableData.Attributes, function(item) { return new Attribute(item); }));
    });

    // Editable Data
    self.criterion = window.ko.observableArray([]);

    // Load initial state from server
    $.getJSON(window.criteriaListUrl, function (availableData) {
        self.criterion($.map(availableData.Criterion, function (item) { return new Criteria(item); }));
    });
}
```

Then, in my HTML, I bind it all together (or, I at least try to):

```
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: criterion">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="selectedAttributes"
                            data-bind="options: $root.availableAttributes, selectedOptions: Attributes, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id'"
                            multiple
                            size="6">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
```

The possible options display correctly. However, there is no apparent binding between the criteria's attributes against the possible options. From reading the guide, it seems as though KO should be able to bind objects directly. Can anybody provide guidance here?

I forgot to mention that everything works *except* the actual binding of the multi-select list. I am applying my bindings appropriately in general - just not with the multi-select list.

Comment: The main parameter for the 'selectedOptions' binding should be an array  (or an observable array). This array will contain the selected values. I would expect to see something like self.chosenAttributes = window.ko.observableArray([]);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attributes property on the Criteria object needs to be an observableArray. Here is a [Jsfiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/tLaSH/)

```
function Criteria(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Attributes = ko.observableArray(data.Attributes);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet (will tomorrow), but the only thing I see different that doesn't match up (which I should be able to change) is that the Criterion Attributes property is an array of Attribute objects - not just an array of the Attribute IDs. Will that make a difference or should the same principles still apply?

Comment: Worked beautifully. I am curious as to why the array of objects doesn't map, but an array of just the IDs maps okay. According to KO.js documentation, objects should map properly. Would appreciate any additional insight if you have it. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

```js
var x= $('#select1 option:selected');
   if(x.length>0){
       x.each(function(){
           alert($(this).text());
        self.selectedCategory.push(new categoryModel($(this).text()));
        $('#select1 option:selected').remove();
       });
   }
```

refer http://jsfiddle.net/deepakpandey1234/wse4gdLq/

Comment: Can you at least explain why your solution is better than what is already the accepted answer?